# Were any of the teachers Harry had for DADA repeat teachers?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Harry Potter universe, the DADA job is portrayed as cursed and each person can only have the job for one year. However, Lupin seems like a really good teacher and I would have expected him to have taught at Hogwarts before. Did he or any of the other teachers Harry had taught before? It doesn’t have to necessarily be Hogwarts that they taught at before.

**EDIT:**
I understand the question wasn't very clear... I meant had any of the DADA teachers Harry had before ever taught DADA before?

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86385/where-had-lupin-taught-before-hogwarts

Comment: You edited to clarify your question, but yet you have accepted an answer for the question you clarified you were **not** asking. I'm confused.

Comment: I thought I had unaccepted that... apparently, my internet connection was not very good... Please excuse that mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Quirinus Quirrel**](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/quirinus-quirrell/) taught Muggle Studies prior to taking the Defense Against the Dark Arts position in Harry's first year.

> Has the jinx on the DADA teaching post at Hogwarts been lifted?
>
> J.K. Rowling: Yes, at last! Incidentally, I know some have asked about Quirrell with regard to this question. He was teaching at Hogwarts for more than a year, but NOT in the post of D.A.D.A. teacher. He was previously Muggle Studies professor.
>
> [<sub>Bloomsbury Live Chat; June 30, 2007</sub>](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/source/interviews/blc/)

Answer (score 3):

## Severus Snape

Snape was originally the Potions professor.

> ‘That’s Professor Snape. He teaches Potions, but he doesn’t want to – everybody knows he’s after Quirrell’s job. Knows an awful lot about the Dark Arts, Snape.’
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*</sub>

He later takes over the role as DADA teacher.

> “Professor Snape, meanwhile,” said Dumbledore, raising his voice so that it carried over all the muttering, “will be taking over the position of Defense Against the Dark Arts teacher.”
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, Chapter 8, Snape Victorious</sub>